# How to use df.rename?

Tags: python, pandas

I am solving an assignment problem from a mooc on Coursera. I have to rename a couple of row labels. I am a new to python and as such often fail to grasp certain nuances as i am fairly certain is the case here. I have tried the rename function as follows

```
energy.set_index('Country', inplace=True)
energy.rename(index={'Republic of Korea':'South Korea', 'United States of 
      America':'United States'})
```

However, the data frame isn't reflecting the change. The following code returns an empty dataframe.

```
energy[energy.index=='South Korea']
```

What am i doing wrong here?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain:

Your code works fine, just is that you need to assign back, like (or use pandas `inplace=True`):

```
energy = energy.rename(index={'Republic of Korea':'South Korea', 
                          'United States of America':'United States'})
```

Or:

```
energy.rename(index={'Republic of Korea':'South Korea', 
                 'United States of America':'United States'},
          inplace=True)
```

Or:

```
energy=energy.rename({'Republic of Korea':'South Korea', 
           'United States of America':'United States'},
           axis="index")
```

Or:

```
energy.rename({'Republic of Korea':'South Korea', 
           'United States of America':'United States'},
           axis="index",inplace=True)
```

Note you can do:

```
energy.loc["South Korea"]
```

Instead of:

```
energy[energy.index=='South Korea']
```

Comment: Yes, to think i had at least 4 ways of doing it correctly makes me feel stupid. I realized i should refer to the docs more often. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @nsus Yeah only one, so which to chose? :-)

Comment: It can definitely be yours :)

Comment: @nsus Thank you so much, :-), i upvoted your question already

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html). What you want is

```
energy = energy.rename(index={'Republic of Korea':'South Korea', 
                              'United States of America':'United States'})
```

or

```
energy.rename(index={'Republic of Korea':'South Korea', 
                     'United States of America':'United States'},
              inplace=True)
```

or

```
energy.rename({'Republic of Korea':'South Korea', 
               'United States of America':'United States'},
               axis="index", inplace=True)
```

Because `inplace` was not set to True, you need to store the return result.

Also, you can just do

```
energy.loc["South Korea"]
```

That is the whole point of having an index - so that you can use keys to access the rows.

Comment: Indeed, I faced the same problem while setting the index. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @nsus You are welcome. Yes, by default many operations on Pandas' DataFrame do not modify it in place. As the developers are very consistent with the names of arguments, it is always a good idea to check if that argument is part of a method's signature even if you don't want to check the docs.

Comment: @nsus, you can upvote the answer  by lightalchemist if that  helps you some or other way around :-)   because time paid here is a  volunteer  contribution and that gives encouragement  to folks contributing here, However i upvoted the the ans already .

Comment: @pygo Since nsus has less then 15 repuation so unable to upvote